# Create ACCDE with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I searched a lot before asking for help.  How may I create an ACCDE file from an existing/working ACCDB, using VB.NET ?  On the machine, Ms Access 2013/2016 is installed.  I know how to do it in VBA, but in my case, I need to do it with Visual Basic/VB.NET.

I explain a little more:  I am creating a tool that will allow the user to select an ACCDB, and the tool will deploy the ACCDE in another folder.  Why you may ask?  Well, the process will also maintain some INI file properties and maintain a Change log file.  Automating the process from my third-party-tool will enhance the deployment process.

I hope you may help me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me in VB.NET 2005 with Access 2010:

```vb
Dim accApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application
accApp.SysCmd(
        CType(603, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction),
       "C:\Users\Public\eTest.accdb",
       "C:\Users\Public\eTest.accde")
accApp.Quit()
```

Note that the source .accdb file must be trusted by Microsoft Access (e.g., in a "Trusted Location") or the command will fail silently.